# Random in a list of lists

Tags: python, pygame

```
def CreateMaze1():
    row1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    row2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    row3 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    row4 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    row5 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    row6 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    row7 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    row8 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    row9 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    row10 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    row11 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    row12 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    row13 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    row14 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    maze= [row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row10, row11, row12, row13, row14]
    return maze
```

I want to select a random element in a list of lists, but it should be 0 and i want to recognise its position so I would be able to replace the 0 in that spot with another element. Can you help me find out how i  could do it?

Comment: Why `rowX = [...]` instead of `return [[...], [...], ...]`?

Comment: Can you describe it in a little more detail? Do you want the position of an element in a list of lists selected randomly and again a random element from that list? But you say if it is not zero, pick another element until it's zero. Am I correct?

Comment: Right! that would be the logic. Amal K

Comment: There is `random.choices(['a','b'],k=20)`.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the position [Row][Pos] and its value

```
maze = CreateMaze1()
import random
randomRow = random.randint(0,len(maze))
randomPos = random.randint(0,len(maze[randomRow]))
print(f"{randomRow}/{randomPos}:{maze[randomRow][randomPos]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick

```
import random


def get_random_element(maze):
    # Assumes the first and the last row do not contain any 0 at all
    rand_row = random.randint(1, len(maze)-1)
    # Assumes the first and last element in every list will always be 1
    rand_index = random.randint(1, len(maze[rand_row])-1)

    if maze[rand_row][rand_index] != 0:
        raise RuntimeError()

    return maze[rand_row][rand_index], (rand_row, rand_index)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    maze = CreateMaze1()
    print(get_random_element(maze))
```

and the output will be

```
# Value=0, (list with index=4 and index of the random element=11)
(0, (4, 11))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly more optimized ways of doing this using arrays and numpy, but this will solve the problem at least. It will continue to generate coordinates and check against the maze to ensure that they are equal to zero before returning.

```
def find_zero_element(maze):
    val = None
    while val != 0:
        x = random.randint(0,len(maze[0])-1) #Assumption: assumes all rows are equal length
        y = random.randint(0,len(maze)-1)
        val = maze[y][x]
    return x,y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `random` module.

- Pick a list from the list of lists using `random.choice()`
- Pick a random index of this list using `random.randint()` and keep picking till the value of the element at that index is 0.

```
import random 


maze = CreateMaze1()

#Select a random list
rand_list = random.choice(maze)

#Select a random element from this list until the element is 0
pos = 0
while True:
    pos = random.randint(0, len(rand_list)-1)
    if rand_list[pos] == 0:
         break
#You can modify this value using rand_list[pos]; pos is the index of the random element in the random list which is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses numpy for fast zeros search

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
from random import choices

def get_random_zero(maze, number = 1):
  """ Gets random location of zero from maze 
   Returns row/column of zero """

   # Find locations of zeros  
  rows, columns = np.where(np.array(maze)==0)

  # return random row/column locations
  return choices(list(zip(rows, columns)), k = number)
```

## Usage

```
maze = CreateMaze1()

# Select 5 zero points
result = get_random_zero(maze, 5)
for row, column in result:
  print(f'row: {row}, column: {column}, maze value: {maze[row][column]}')
```

**Output**

```
row: 2, column: 2, maze value: 0
row: 10, column: 1, maze value: 0
row: 2, column: 4, maze value: 0
row: 1, column: 1, maze value: 0
row: 5, column: 5, maze value: 0
```